# Apply changes : Manifest always considered as modified

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working for a client which has a very big application, so the feature apply changes would be great for me, because builds can be very long and so can be reaching the screen I'm working on.

The problem is that every time I try to apply changes, android studio tells me that the manifest has been modified so the changes cannot be applied, and a full restart is then done.
I've checked the manifest, and several gradle variables are there, but their value don't seem to change between builds (**they only change when build variant is switched**).

Can this be a bug in the apply changes feature, or is there something else I could check ?